# JS with PHP: if/else

Tags: javascript

Can i do this?:

```
$(window).focus(function() {
<?php if(session....) ?>
...$.ajax...
<?php }else{
header('');
}
?>
});
```

Comment: have you tried it? what happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, but keep in mind that the PHP `if-else` is executed on the server and only once, so the resulting JS will contain either the `$.ajax` call or nothing at all - this won't change once the page has loaded.

Also, you can't usually call `header` after you've already sent some output (unless you're using output buffering).

Comment: Yes so what else can I do then to make it check more than once?

Comment: @Johnson: Then you have to write all the code in JavaScript. However, there's no way to access the PHP session from JavaScript. One way is to add another AJAX call to a PHP script that returns the value within the `if` statement, then check it in JavaScript.